# Marketing Cloud contact builder shows 9 times more contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We synced contacts from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud. 
Data sources and it's related entities display 118,704 contacts got synced from Salesforce.

But in Contact builder it is showing 9,34,276 contacts.

We are assuming of possible duplicates. Attched are the screenshots for reference.
**How do we know the source of sync of 9L contacts?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: that count is  all contacts in marketing cloud account not Contact_Salesforce

Comment: Second screen shot only contacts sync from Sales force if you have doubt mean check in sales force using query like select id from Contact  like that

Comment: Yeah, right. But we wanted to know if 1Lakh contacts got synced from Salesforce how is Marketing cloud displaying 9Lakh? How do i know the source of those 9Lakhs?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, All Contacts contain mainly:

- All contacts from All Subscribers
- All contacts from Mobile Connect that are available in all your bus
- Salesforce Contacts
- Salesforce Leads
- Salesforce Users

For a full list check the following article: [Contact Definition and Count Determination](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5). Contacts are counted regardless of the fact if you tried to contact them or not.

There's also a nice article that shows how to remove unwanted customers:
[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271352&language=en_US&type=1)

**Analyzing All Contacts**

If you change the process described in the last article, you can get the list that contains every contact in All Contacts:

1. Create a filtered list in Mobile Connect with a single condition `Contact Key is not null`
2. Create a data extension with a single "SubscriberKey"
3. Query the filtered list and send the results to your data extensions:

`Select SubscriberKey from [Your MobileConnect list name from step 1]`

After the query completes you can anylyze the DE in any way you want - either by queries or externally in whatever software you choose.

Answer (score 0):

```
In first screen shot count is All Contacts in salesforce marketing cloud account and 
Second screen shot count is only contacts sync from Sales force  if you have doubt mean 
check in sales force using query like **select id from Contact in Developer console 
   query Editor**
```

Comment: Yeah, right. But we wanted to know if 1Lakh contacts got synced from Salesforce how is Marketing cloud displaying 9Lakh? How do i know the source of those 9Lakhs?

Comment: i think that count is  all contacts  in sales force marketing cloud i mean All subscriber count and also deleted contacts

Comment: first you check  all subscriber count you get some idea